# jQuery Validation Input value not begining with multiple paterns

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I started using jQuery validation on this new project I'm working on, and I've been struggling to find a rule to validate if a text input doesn't start "057" or "089" or "093.

I know there is a notEqual rule that matches the whole input value,
is there any way I can achieve the same but only for the first 3 characters?

Comment: You can use `match` with `jQuery.validator.addMethod()`

Comment: Thanks @Alex, what's the regex method to match with not starting with "057" or "089" or "093 ??

Comment: Off the top of my head, something like `^(057|089|093)\d*` Not had a chance to test it

Comment: Or use the default `pattern` rule that is part of the `additional-methods.js` file.

Comment: Have you seen [RegExr](https://regexr.com)?

Comment: post your code here, so that we can understand the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with something like that:

```
// Custom validation
$.validator.addMethod('customInput', function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(057|089|093)/.test(value);
});
```

Comment: // Thank you, This worked for me i just had to change the Regex to /^(057|089|093)/